# mod_rewrite rule is not working but I have the correct syntax

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

So my mod_rewrite rule isn't working to specify a specific php file for a URL.

```
Options -Indexes
php_value short_open_tag 1

#Caching
# 1 HOUR
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 HOUR
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 HOUR
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Rewrite rules
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^about\/special-offers\/?$ about/special-offers.php


# remove www. from all domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Add trailing slash
# TODO: This breaks POST data when forwarding to a URL without an ending slash
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|gif|jpe?g|JPE?G|png|bmp|js|swf|css|ico|xml|txt|woff2|woff)$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [P,R=301]

# hide .svn folders
RewriteRule ^(.*/)*\.svn/ / [NC,L]

# send all images and misc files to the actual location
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|JPE?G|png|bmp|js|swf|ico|xml|txt) index.php [NC,L]

# send folder to the relevant php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/$2.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/ $1/$2.php

#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/$2.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/default.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# otherwise if the file or directory is not found, process through the index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have a multitude of other rules in here, I can post them if need be, but since this is a specific rule I don't know why one of them would be overriding it.  Direction is appreciated.

I've tried putting it at the top or bottom of my mod_rewrite section but neither seems to have any affect.

*Something I've just noticed is that when I go to `/about/special-offers/x` (where x is any string), it loads the correct page.*

Other

Comment: Try and disable `MultiViews`, that is usually the culprit when things go wrong in cases where you have such a partial overlap between fake URL and real existing file system content.

Comment: Hmm, I've disabled MultiViews but still no luck.

Comment: See if https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ can shed some light on what is going on; if not, then show us your complete rewrite setup.

Comment: (“Escaping” the slashes inside the expression should not be necessary. But at least according to the mentioned test tool, it seems to do no harm either.)

Comment: Using the tool it seems like my first, explicit rewrite works (/special-offers.php).  But my subdirectory rewrite `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/ $1/$2.php` also works after that (/a/b/ to a/b.php)...  But after that rule comes another that redirects to /about/default.php, and the finally to /index.php.  I have multiview disabled, is the priority order for the rewrites top to bottom or bottom to top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed this issue, I did it by marking the RewriteRule as final with [L].

Relevant portion:

```
# send folder to the relevant php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/ $1/$2.php [L]
```